# Grammatical construction of “you don’t necessarily have to” in this sentence

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> And, I should add, that I would remember, at least every now and then, to own up to my own specific tastes and noteworthy eccentricities and allow that just because I think something is good and proper and nifty you don’t necessarily have to.

Could anyone help me understand the grammatical construction of “you don’t necessarily have to” in this sentence?

Comment: With questions like these, it helps if you try to explain how you understand it in your question. That gives a better idea of both your terminology and what you are specifically looking for. For example, what do you think "you don't necessarily have to" connects with?

Comment: To understand the text, you have to hear the stress and intonation. The only way it makes sense is to say _just because_ **I** _think something is good and proper and nifty,_ **you** _don’t necessarily have to_, with contrastive stress on **I** and **you**. The rest is just conjunction reduction. That is, you don't have to agree with me about values.

Answer (score 1):

If you put a comma after nifty, it creates a pause that might help with comprehension:

> "... just because I think something is good and proper and nifty, you don't necessarily have to [**think that as well**]"

Grammatically, you have:

- *you do not* (second person negative of "do")
- *necessarily* (adverb)
- *have to* (**+ omitted verb/verb phrase**) ([modal verb of obligation](https://linguapress.com/grammar/modal-obligation.htm))

In an separate example sentence, you could have:

> He is a gifted thinker and an articulate author; you do not necessarily have to know the complete genealogy of Western philosophy to appreciate his writings.

Answer (score 1):

"just because I think something is good and proper and nifty **you don’t necessarily have to**.” =

"just because I think something is good and proper and nifty, **it is not necessary for you to** [think something is good and proper and nifty]."